# Excel VBA - AdvancedFilter

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to filter a range dynamically in VBA and the VBA I am using is not working but I cannot see a logical reason as to why. To explain, I have a range of data in a sheet entitled "`Full Stock Report`" the size of which will change but I've set it statically in this example... And I'm trying to filter it by a list of criteria held in a range on a sheet initiated "`Spitfire Aval Locations`", again this is also dynamic but I've set as static again in this example. This sounds simple to me but the below line of code applies a filter but with no results (I have checked I know there are lots that should appear from this filter).

My second question is related, how does this VBA statement dictate which column in the range is being filtered ? (I fear this may be my issue ....)

```
Sheets("Full Stock Report").Range("A1:F20623").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, 
      CriteriaRange:=Sheets("Spitfire Aval Locations").range("A2:A228"), Unique:=False
```

Comment: In this case the macro recorder might help. Record, do what needs to be done, stop recording and adjust the macro.

Comment: I tried that, but unfortunatley, same result, hence the predicament

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The column to filter on is the first .Range that you call .AdvancedFilter on.  The code you posted filters columns A through F.  If you wanted to only filter based on values in column A, it would look more like this:

```
Sheets("Full Stock Report").Range("A1:A20623").AdvancedFilter _
       Action:=xlFilterInPlace, _
       CriteriaRange:=Sheets("Spitfire Aval Locations").Range("A2:A228"), _
       Unique:=False
```

Comment: Excellent point, thank you, and i was expecting that - but how does it know the full range to filter, even though its filtering against one column ?

Comment: @DJDave022002 - I'm not sure I understand the question - filtering hides entire rows, so you only need to include the columns that you want filtered against your criteria.

Comment: Another good point, appolagies i didn't consider the fact that it doesnt filter a specific range, stupid schoolboy mistake, I was looking at the defined range rather than considering it wikll hide entire rows regadless of defined range. Sorry...

Comment: Sorry -- That does make sense, however it yields no result when tried, even though i know the main list to contain many entries that exist in the criteria list.

Answer (score 1):

Think I've solved this ... essentially AdvancedFilter requires the criteria to be the same format and same column titles as your data set. Not hugeley helpful to me, but I can bodge it to work.

I also have a hunch that AutoFilter with specified criteria might be a better option...

Comment: Good point Dave. I've also struggeled with this method and this is the solution!