# VBA AdvancedFilter CriteriaRange reference (formatting?) issue

Tags: advanced-filter

My macro is referencing a criteria range in one workbook (text values) and filters data in another workbook (using that range). However, the filtered list is empty (only contains headers).  I tried testing many different ways and have isolated the issue to, probably, the formatting of my criteria range. I.e. if I pass it text values via array (using Autofilter instead), it works, but not when referencing a range in excel (with AdvancedFilter). Criteria range ("E2:E5") is formatted as "General" and appears in a single column like this:

```
WFHF62330002
WFHF63840002
WFHF64540002
```

Does CriteriaRange take values as a column or row, i.e. do I need to transpose these into a row (tried - doesn't work)? Or is there a way to bring it to text formatting in some way? Not sure how to go about this issue.

Relevant code:

```
With wb_input.Worksheets("TempSheet").Range("A1:Y99999")

.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, CriteriaRange:=wb_output.Sheets("Setup").Range("E2:E15")

End With
```

> I'm not posting the whole macro - hopefully the explanation above is sufficient. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You have to include the Header to your Criteria Range - Criteria range ("E1:E5"), if the cell "E1" is the Header :-) And the Header must be the same as the Header in the Sheet where you are applying the Filter.

See here in this post:
[Excel VBA - AdvancedFilter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29716748/excel-vba-advancedfilter)

Comment: Thank you so much! This is very helpful.